# Login successful but unable to open the next activity

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity

I have login successfully without the intent. But when I add the Customer Activity intent it gives me an force closed error when trying to login. I have a listview of 5 diff. activities within the customer.java and they all open with no problem. Im wondering why the Login is giving the error

Login.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Login extends Activity {
    private EditText etUsername;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private TextView lblResult;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Login
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();

            if(username.equals("guest")){
                lblResult.setText("Login successful.");




                Intent i = new Intent("com.merrill.Customer");
                startActivity(i);


            } else {
                 lblResult.setText("Login failed. Username doesn't match.");
             }
            }
            });


            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Close the application
            finish();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.royalcabinets.merrill"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Login"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.merrill.Customer"
                  android:label="Customer Service Group">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
       </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Ronnie´s response or

```
    Intent i= new Intent(Login.this, Customer.class);
```

or

```
Intent i= new Intent(this, Customer.class);
```

or

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customer.class);
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.royalcabinets.merrill"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Login"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name="Customer"
                  android:label="Customer Service Group">
            </activity>
       </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The 'this' gave an error but the getApplicationContext() works. Can you can explain how and why that would work over 'this'

Comment: ups really? =| well heres the explanation getApplicationContext() :: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29

Comment: the reason `this` gives you an error is that you're invoking the `startActivity` from within the anonymous inner class [which you've registered as a listener]. `this` at that point refers to the anonymous inner class' instance. whereas `getApplicationContext` or `Login.this` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in having two points of entry for your app. The `Manifest` should have only one `Activity` marked with the `intent-filter` action for `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

Besides that, I still feel there can be other sources of problems in your code. I suggest you fire up the `ddms` tool. [go to the terminal/command prompt and execute the `ddms.bat` file in your `android-sdk\tools` folder]. Set a filter to print the `Errors`, and you'll find some meaningful message.

post that, and we can take it forward - that is, if removing the extra `MAIN` `Activity` doesn't work.

Comment: actually without those activity marked with intent-filter, my customer.java wouldn't have worked (the one with listview and each item have its own activities) 5 items in the listview, 5 diff. class, and last 5 activities in the manifest with the android.intent.action.MAIN